# Organization of Initialization code

Tags: c++, winapi, organization, code-organization

Good day,

I have been working on memory allocations for portable use.

I have a header file which contains function prototypes and operator overloads for new and delete.

```
void* mem_align16(size_t size);
void mem_delete16(void* memory);
```

I then have cpp files for each operating system implementation.
for example sbrk for linux and HeapAlloc for windows.

when working with windows I must use a handle to do memory allocations.

```
HANDLE heap_handle = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);
```

How would I use the handle in an organized clean manner? As the handle would need to be used at startup inside of main. The only way I can think of using the handle is by having it as a static variable inside of the cpp file where the functions are used and then use a function to update the static variable and then have it forward declared inside of main.cpp

```
//inside of win32_heap.cpp
static HANDLE heaphandle = 0;

void make_heap_handle(void) {
    heaphandle = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);
}

//inside of win32_main.cpp
void make_heap_handle(void);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    make_heap_handle();
    return (0);
}
```

For some reason this feels like the wrong thing to do in order to get a usable handle for use with my functions.

Comment: For portable use, what's wrong with the facilities of the C++ Standard Library, and a Standard C++ compliant compiler?

Comment: Given that `HANDLE` is system-specific, requiring it to be exposed to `main()` is hardly portable.    Organise your code so such details are not exposed outside your functions.   Beyond that, your question is unclear.    (Agree with Neil Butterworth's comment too - there is no value in rolling your own memory management, if you are seeking a portable solution).

Comment: [operator new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) offers everything you are asking for (presumably, a non-throwing allocation with specific alignment requirements).

Comment: @Peter But `HANDLE` is not exposed to `main()`, is it?  Only `make_heap_handle()`, and that just needs a more sensible name, like (say) `init_memory_manager()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `HeapCreate()` in order to use `HeapAlloc()`/`HeapFree()`, you could just use `GetProcessHeap()` instead:

```
void* mem_align16(size_t size)
{
    // adjust size as needed...
    void *memory = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size);
    if (!memory) return nullptr;
    // adjust memory as needed ...
    return memory;
}

void mem_delete16(void* memory)
{
    // adjust memory as needed...
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, memory);
}
```

However, if you do want to create a private heap of your own, you can create a singleton class that is hidden inside your `win32_heap.cpp` file to create and destroy your private heap.  The rest of your code outside of `win32_heap.cpp` will not be privy to its existence:

```
class MyHeap
{
public:
    HANDLE hHeap;

    MyHeap() {
        hHeap = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);
    }

    ~MyHeap() {
        HeapDestroy(hHeap);
    }
};

static MyHeap gMyHeap;

void* mem_align16(size_t size)
{
    // adjust size as needed...
    void *memory = HeapAlloc(gMyHeap.hHeap, 0, size);
    if (!memory) return 0;
    // adjust memory as needed ...
    return memory;
}

void mem_delete16(void* memory)
{
    // adjust memory as needed...
    HeapFree(gMyHeap.hHeap, 0, memory);
}
```

Comment: Or even just: `static HANDLE gMyHeap = HeapCreate (...)` since there is no need to destroy it when the program terminates.